# Updated Nvidia graphics driver, now won't make it past the boot screen

Tags: boot, nvidia, updates

I recently installed a ASUS GTX560 graphics card in my desktop and out of the box everything was working fine. I decided to check for available updates and one of the suggested ones was the most current Nvidia driver. After Instillation, I rebooted and now the OS makes it to one screen past the boot loader. It is a screen with multiple tests being run and a few of the answers are "no". I tried booting in recovery and safe mode and removing the Nvidia driver update through the terminal but still to no avail. I don't want to have to do a clean install of ubuntu to get my system back because I have 3 years worth of files on the disk. I feel very lost after spending hours on the forums and I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?  Getting to a recovery console root prompt with RW differs on some of them.

Answer (score 2):

**On 12.04 Latest** - tested, steps should basically apply for previous.
If it doesn't work, add the output from `fdisk -l` and `mount` from recovery console in your question and I'll edit my answer to address it.

Boot to recovery console
Select root shell

```
mount
```

Should give you some output, you're looking for the one that has `on / type` in it.

```
/dev/sda7 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
```

You need to remount it read-write:

```
mount -o remount,rw /dev/sda7
```

Now we need to find the driver to uninstall:

```
jockey-text --no-dbus -l
```

Don't worry abound the error messages, you want the last two lines
One of them should read something like:

```
xorg:nvidia_current - something (Proprietary, Enabled, In use)
```

or

```
xorg:nvidia_current_updates - something (Proprietary, Enabled, In use)
```

You want whichever one is `Enabled`

```
jockey-text --no-dbus --disable=xorg:nvidia_current
sync
init 6
```

It should reboot you in to a GUI now using the noveau open source driver.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try and download the drivers manually and install them (from nvidia). But you may need to modify the GRUB string to nomodeset. Also some people have fixed it by: `sudo apt-get install lightdm-gtk-greeter`