# HDMI not detected Ubuntu 12.10 - ATI Radeon HD 6670

Tags: 12.10, graphics, radeon, hdmi, fglrx

Brand new to Linux, so help a young blood out :-) (I'm a novice/hobby programmer, but completely new to Linux command syntax, etc)

Brand new everything Rig. Fresh install of Ubuntu 12.10. Ubuntu installed everything and updates. I am getting VGA output and sound through standard sound port on mb. However the HDMI port on the radeon card is not recognized and not available. Any help getting this detected and usable?

Comment: What driver do You have?

Comment: I should mention I'm using VGA through GPU, not mb. Just using onboard sound port while HDMI is out

Comment: @zuberuber it's fglrx (We've been trying to work this out on G+)

Comment: @KeithWilson have you tried using the Catalyst Control Centre?

Comment: Not sure I have that control center.

Comment: Found it, installing

Comment: Ok the catalyst control center is saying that I dont have the correct driver installed. Thought during software updates it grabbed the proprietary one. But guess not. I do have the AMD site download file but it doesnt want to install

Comment: "One or more tools required for installation cannot be found on the system.
Install the required tools before installing the fglrx driver. Optionally, run the installer... [then see log file]

Comment: Log File:
"Supported adapter detected.
Check if system has the tools required for installation.
fglrx installation requires that the system have kernel headers.  /lib/modules/3.5.0-18-generic/build/include/linux/version.h cannot be found on this system.
One or more tools required for installation cannot be found on the system. Install the required tools before installing the fglrx driver.
Optionally, run the installer with --force option to install without the tools.
Forcing install will disable AMD hardware acceleration and may make your system unstable. Not recommended."

Comment: @KeithWilson don't (please don't!) install the drivers from AMD's site!

The supported (and best method) is to install them using the built in driver tool. Go to System Settings, click software sources, and then click the tab that says "Additional Drivers", and install it from there.

Comment: Reinstalling Ubuntu. Will give it a go in a minute :-)

Comment: OK, Reinstalled and then did the additional drivers. Catalyst control center says no driver installed.. help!

Answer (score 1):

If it's missing the version.h file, that is supposed to be included with linux-headers, at least on my install.

If you're missing a file `sudo apt-get install apt-file`
Then `apt-file search **filename**`.  It will ask you to update the apt-file cache, so do what it tells you.

You should see something like:
`apt-file search linux/version.h`

```
linux-headers-3.2.y-xx-generic: /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.y-xx/include/linux/version.h
```

If that file exists, something with softlinks got messed up.
`apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers-generic`

Comment: Problem is, the additional drivers I install actually make the system hang after login. Can't do anything .... No chance to revert. I could try another install... Do the additional drivers... And then your fix perhaps before rebooting again

Comment: Just reread your comment. Realized I misunderstood. Will reinstall Ubuntu and check for the headers before updating drivers

Comment: If you want to remove the driver without reinstalling, I wrote this answer for a similar situation: http://askubuntu.com/questions/124878/updated-nvidia-graphics-driver-now-wont-make-it-past-the-boot-screen/124895#124895 obviously change nvidia to the name of the ati driver

Comment: Going to try Ubuntu 12.04 LTS tonight and see how that goes with my video card drivers. Keep ya posted!

Comment: system is up running 12.04 LTS. Driver installation worked via ubuntu however there are 2 drivers and the one marked "post release update" doesnt install. heh. Still unable to see the HDMI ... continuing to investigate

Comment: post release update not installing is a known bug.  it's open on launchpad