# Cannot enter ubuntu graphical environment after update

Tags: 12.04, updates, white-screen

I was using ubuntu 12.04 LTS version and everything was working fine. Yesterday I decided to update using the option in the update manager to ubuntu 14. Everything went smoothly in the installation BUT after the restart when I tried to boot ubuntu I was stuck in a grey/white screen (no login possible)...
Please tell me that there is a solution in this that does not require complete format of the operating system! I am not proficient in using ubuntu so please if you make any suggestion like check graphic card do tell me how to do it or redirect me to an adequate tutorial...

Comment: Try reinstalling ubuntu-desktop like this sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop

Comment: I do not have access to terminal... And if I press 'c' in grub it does not recognise the sudo command...

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Reinstall Ubuntu or use LiveDVD, because tty doesn't work

Try Ctrl + Alt + F6 to enter tty6. (Also possible with 1-5)

There you can try to [reinstall ubuntu-desktop](http://itsfoss.com/fix-unity-freezes-after-login-ubuntu-14-04/) or [choose another window manager](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162516/switching-window-manager-desktop-environments)

Comment: Those are very good links! But I have one problem...I cannot open the terminal! None of the combinations to open it work...

Comment: never had this...
Probably easiest solution: reinstalling the system; You can save your data probably by booting with the live Disc and saving them to an external drive for example

Comment: if you definitely don't want to reinstall, maybe some additional information would help:
You "tried to login" so you see an login screen? does Crtl + Alt +F6 anything before trying to login?

Comment: I do not see a login screen instead of it I see a white/grey screen... I tried Crtl+Alt+F6 in there and before selecting ubuntu in grub...

Comment: have you tried selecting sth else to boot in grub? e.g. recovery mode for ubuntu

Comment: I have tried every option in the recovery mode...nothing works ...I guess something must have reaaaaally went wrong in the upgrade...

Comment: again I'd recommend a fresh install of ubuntu; is there a specific reason why you don't want to do this?
Do you run a dual boot with win or sth? Does the other OS work?

Comment: I am running dual boot with windows 7...I did not want to format because I am running short in time for a project and it would take to much time to reinstall all the additional programs... But it seems that it is unavoidable!

Comment: Does you win work? If it does you can just reinstall ubuntu, therefore try booting with liveDisc and [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1649489); [explanation here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17823/how-to-list-all-installed-packages)

Comment: If win doesn't work the error is maybe in grub; you can try [this](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd); [if you understand German here in nicer form](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/GRUB_2/Reparatur#Reparatur-mittels-Desktop-CD)

Comment: If win does work another option might be trying to install another graphics driver. You can try sth similar to [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/245410/how-to-install-uninstall-a-driver-on-a-frozen-system-using-a-livecd), depending on your card

Comment: Windows work thank you for your help you redirected me to some pretty good tutorials. But I have decided to do a format and get it over with because nothing that I have been trying did any good...

Comment: That is probably the easiest solution. You're welcome :)